# Object comparison inside and outside a class

Tags: c#, class, object, compare, object-composition

I have two classes, the first class `Movie` has one attribute `string name`. The second class `Festival` has also one attribute `Movie[] movies`.
The following method which I wrote inside of the class `Festival` checks if `Movie mv` exists in `movies` and returns `true` or `false` accordingly:

```
public bool Exist(Movie mv)
    {
        foreach (Movie movie in movies)
        {
            if (mv == movie)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The method works perfectly and returns `true` when `mv` exists in `movies`, and `false` when it isn't.

But when I tried to make a function in class `Program` named `Check` which gets `Festival f1`, and `Festival f2` and checks if the festivals have a movie in common, the following method always returned `false`:

```
public static bool Check(Festival f1, Festival f2)
    {
        foreach (Movie movie1 in f1.GetMovies() //returns festival only attributed: movies)
        {
            foreach (Movie movie2 in f2.GetMovies())
            {
                if (movie2 == movie1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

So I tried to use the `Object.Equals(Object)` method but the following code has also always returned `false`:

```
public static bool Check(Festival f1, Festival f2)
    {
        foreach (Movie movie1 in f1.GetMovies())
        {
            foreach (Movie movie2 in f2.GetMovies())
            {
                if (movie2.Equals(movie1))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The only case I succeeded make it work was when I compared the two objects attribute by using the method `GetName()` that returns the `name` of the `Movie`:

```
public static bool Check(Festival f1, Festival f2)
    {
        foreach (Movie movie1 in f1.GetMovies())
        {
            foreach (Movie movie2 in f2.GetMovies())
            {
                if (movie2.GetName() == movie1.GetName())
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Can someone please explain why the first and last attempts worked, and the other two didn't?

Comment: Show Movie.Equals method

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You created equals method for comparing movies, can you show it, i think problem is here

Comment: no no I used the object.equals method

Comment: Oh, okay, it`s clear now

Comment: Please review [mre] guidance on posting code. We don't know how `GetMovies` works so there is no way to *definitely* explain what is going on. While [edit] the question with updated code also make sure to explain why you expected `movie2 == movie1` to behave differently from `movie2.Equals(movie1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I will catch all snippets by order.

First snip, i guess movies object is a global variable and you pass movie as member of collection - Exist(movies[0]), that`s working, because reference the same, if you try to create custom object with field value, that present in list - it will return false.

Next, you can't use Object.Equals for checking your custom objects, you need to override it, [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-6.0) you can see how to do it.
In a row you tried to do movie2 == movie1. That`s didn't work with the same reason - you didn't override == operator. [There](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type) is an explanation

The last one is working proper way, because it`s checking real data, names of your movies, which makes sence